# Finding recently downloaded files on Windows

Tags: search

On Windows 8 I'd like a list of all the recently downloaded files (say, in the past few weeks, or a month). These files are saved to a directory structure, so they're not all simply in a single folder for easy identification.

For each file I'm seeing Date Created and Date Modified properties but these are set to the dates the downloaded files were initially created or accessed, not date when the file was created on my system at the time of the download. Does such a property exist?

Ironically, I use the Firefox add-in DownThemAll which has a list of the files downloaded, but it can find no way to export that list for further processing.

Appreciate any guidance, thanks.

Comment: Write a Powershell script to perform a recursive function on the parent folder and generate the list that way.

Comment: Which DownThemAll! version are you using? There's an export feature since version 1.1.

Comment: Can you not use the built in Windows search feature (WinKey+F) and do a search for all files modified within X time frame? Also, the 'date created' date would be the date the file was 'first' on your system at the time of download...but those dates only matter if something didn't modify them externally (those dates are not hard coded and can be changed by any program with the rights)

Comment: Appreciate the responses, thanks. DownTheAll, does indeed have an export function, but it doesn't export all its data. In the end I found the easiest approach was the track down its SQLite datastore and just interrogate it myself. Turned out to be fairly straightforward once I got comfortable decoding the JSON data format it uses to put all the data in one field (rather than have individual fields in the db). Thanks again.